# SyntaxError EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

I'm trying to use this Python one liner script:

```
python -c 'import hashlib,hmac; hash=raw_input("Hash > "); salt=raw_input("Salt > "); print "HMAC",hmac.new(salt,hash,hashlib.sha1).hexdigest().upper()'
```

And it gives me this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I'm using Windows 10 64bit and I'm working with ConEmu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single or double quotes within Python, but at the command-line terminal (cmd or Powershell) you have to use double quotes to enclose the argument you wish to send. Enclose it with double quotes, and use single quotes within it:

```
python -c "import hashlib,hmac; hash=raw_input('Hash > '); salt=raw_input('Salt > '); print 'HMAC',hmac.new(salt,hash,hashlib.sha1).hexdigest().upper()"
```

Comment: @AlbertPike - Glad to hear it. You can indicate that this answer resolved the issue by clicking the check mark below its score.